# Telerik RadComboBox only opens on the second click

Tags: javascript, telerik

I'm new to telerik components, and I have a strange problem.

I'm populating a `RadComboBox` through JS by calling `requestItems` based on another combobox selection.

The data populates correctly, but visually only when I click on the combobox a second time does the list appear.

In the source, the data exists, but all the `rcbItem` have display none , and `rcbScroll` `rcbWidth` as a `height of 0px`. Only on the second click does the list appear.

Here's the JS code:

```
//global variables for the countries and cities comboboxes
var ouCombo;
var dsCombo;
var searchBox;

    function pageLoad() {
        ouCombo = $find("<%= UnitRadComboBox.ClientID %>");
        dsCombo = $find("<%= ServiceRadComboBox.ClientID %>");
        searchBox = $find("<%= SearchRadTextBox.ClientID %>")
    }

    function loadDepartments(sender, eventArgs) {
        var item = eventArgs.get_item();
        dsCombo.set_text("A carregar...");
        // if a continent is selected
        if (item.get_index() > 0) {
            // this will fire the ItemsRequested event of the 
            // combobox passing the ID as a parameter 
            dsCombo.requestItems(item.get_value(), false);
        }
        else {
            // the - empty - item was chosen
            dsCombo.set_text(" ");
            dsCombo.clearItems();
        }
    }

    function ItemsLoaded(sender, eventArgs) {
        if (sender.get_items().get_count() > 0) {
            // pre-select the first item
            sender.set_text("Escolha uma opçao");
            //sender.get_items().getItem(0).highlight();
            //sender.showDropDown();
            var radInput = $find("<%= SearchRadTextBox.ClientID %>");
            radInput.focus();
        }
    }
```

Here's the markup

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox ID="UnitRadComboBox" runat="server" OnItemsRequested="UnitRadComboBox_ItemsRequested1"
            HighlightTemplatedItems="true" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" OnClientSelectedIndexChanging="loadDepartments"
            OnClientItemsRequested="ItemsLoaded" LoadingMessage="A carregar..." Skin="Default">
            <CollapseAnimation Type="OutQuint" Duration="200" />
</telerik:RadComboBox>

<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ServiceRadComboBox" runat="server" HighlightTemplatedItems="true"
            EnableLoadOnDemand="true" Filter="StartsWith" OnItemsRequested="ServiceRadComboBox_ItemsRequested"
            OnClientItemsRequested="ItemsLoaded" Width="250px" LoadingMessage="A carregar...">
            <CollapseAnimation Type="OutQuint" Duration="200" />
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: please post your asp.net markup as well. thx

Answer (score 0):

Delete: `sender.set_text("Escolha uma opçao");` and see if that works.

Comment: Please explain your anwswer in more detail. What would your answer change?